# Ident authentication failed for user "graphite"

Tags: django, postgresql, graphite

I'm in the process of installing Graphite.  I'm using postgresql under Centos 7.3.  When I go to import the django schema into postgres, I get the following TB:

```
[root@hera graphite]# PYTHONPATH=$GRAPHITE_ROOT/webapp django-admin.py migrate --settings=graphite.settings --run-syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 89, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 175, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "graphite"
```

I've added the graphite user to postgres and verified that the correct postgres user name, password and database engine are in local_settings.py.  Any ideas where I might have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happen to walk into the same problem this afternoon on RHEL 7.3. In my case i edited /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf and changed the line:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
```

to:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

then restart postgresql. Also it's good to verify/check if you actually can log in with the user to postgres and have the correct database permissions.